# datatool error ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>

Tags: datatool

My `sample.tex` is -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{coefficient}{coefficient.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLfetch{coefficient}{academicYear}{Estimate}
\end{document}
```

and `coefficient.csv` is -

```
"","Estimate","Pr(>|t|)"
"(Intercept)",3083.10823266321,0.410258948870845
"academicYear",-154.682625625893,0.586945960271761
"tuitionOfferPerMonth",166.418331237849,0.626598991149528
"tutionsYouHaveDone",88.1170833442809,0.687790764988264
"result",2174.73550930876,0.0319792901914711
"teachingHour",762.859932701096,0.421832171976142
"subjectsYouTaught",-99.4216388435531,0.831181012593366
"daysInWeek",-471.260444393369,0.409951748818405
"tuitionType",469.36175552496,0.446727615621479
"studentClass",159.808778458308,0.249053825131443
"Dept.science",1902.80982919603,0.105027526587972
"Hall",-1057.61231171402,0.196789600388924
```

The `sample.tex` results -

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))) (./delete.aux
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \dtl@ci@coefficient@academicYear 
l.6 \end
        {document}
?
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

`\DTLfetch` requires four arguments: *database label*, *column1 key*, *value*, *column2 key*. It's designed to find the first row where the column given by *column1 key* matches *value* and returns the value from the column identified by *column2 key* the same row.

Your data doesn't have a label for the first column, so I recommend you use the `keys` option to assign column labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[keys={description,Estimate,Pr}]{coefficient}{coefficient.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLfetch{coefficient}{description}{academicYear}{Estimate}
\end{document}
```